# How to convert below api response which is in xml format to c# class?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, api

I had posted a question regarding how to call api which is in xml format.
[Calling api in xml format in c# - Getting error "Remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62021295/calling-api-in-xml-format-in-c-sharp-getting-error-remote-certificate-is-inva)

Now I am getting a response from the api.  But now I want to convert the response  to c# object. The attributes of xml changes in case of success and failure.

**Below response if everything is success..**

```
<FIXML xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.finacle.com/fixml BalInq.xsd" xmlns="http://www.finacle.com/fixml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> <Header> <ResponseHeader> <RequestMessageKey> <RequestUUID>Req_1560515797477</RequestUUID> <ServiceRequestId>BalInq</ServiceRequestId> <ServiceRequestVersion>10.2</ServiceRequestVersion> <ChannelId>COR</ChannelId> </RequestMessageKey> <ResponseMessageInfo> <BankId>01</BankId> <TimeZone>GMT+05:30</TimeZone> <MessageDateTime>2020-05-29T12:39:13.379</MessageDateTime> </ResponseMessageInfo><UBUSTransaction> <Id/> <Status/> </UBUSTransaction> <HostTransaction> <Id/> <Status>SUCCESS</Status> </HostTransaction> <HostParentTransaction> <Id/> <Status/> </HostParentTransaction> <CustomInfo/> </ResponseHeader> </Header> <Body> <BalInqResponse> <BalInqRs> <AcctId> <AcctId>4362500100484501</AcctId> <AcctType> <SchmCode></SchmCode> <SchmType></SchmType> </AcctType> <AcctCurr>INR</AcctCurr> <BankInfo> <BankId></BankId> <Name></Name> <BranchId>436</BranchId> <BranchName></BranchName> <PostAddr> <Addr1></Addr1> <Addr2></Addr2> <Addr3></Addr3> <City></City> <StateProv></StateProv> <PostalCode></PostalCode> <Country></Country> <AddrType></AddrType> </PostAddr> </BankInfo> </AcctId> <AcctBal> <BalType>CLRBAL</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>2.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>SANLIM</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>UTLAMT</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>DRWPWR</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>ADHOC</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>SINTRN</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>CLNADH</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>DACC</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>LIEN</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>SYSRES</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>OVDFUT</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>DAFALM</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>FUTBAL</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>FLOAT</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>AVAIL</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>2.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>FFDAVL</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>EFFAVL</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>2.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>EFUAVL</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode></currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>EMRADV</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>CLNEMR</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>CLNSTR</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>SYSGENLM</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>UNCLRBAL</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>POOLAVL</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>HOMAVL</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>FUTCR</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>UTILFUTBAL</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>USEDOC</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode>INR</currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> <AcctBal> <BalType>DAFAWITHDRAWL</BalType> <BalAmt> <amountValue>0.00</amountValue> <currencyCode></currencyCode> </BalAmt> </AcctBal> </BalInqRs><BalInq_CustomData/> </BalInqResponse></Body></FIXML>
```

**Below response in case of failure**

```
<FIXML xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.finacle.com/fixml BalInq.xsd" xmlns="http://www.finacle.com/fixml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
<ResponseHeader>
<RequestMessageKey>
<RequestUUID>Req_1560515797477</RequestUUID>
<ServiceRequestId>BalInq</ServiceRequestId>
<ServiceRequestVersion>10.2</ServiceRequestVersion>
<ChannelId>COR</ChannelId>
</RequestMessageKey>
<ResponseMessageInfo>
<BankId>01</BankId>
<TimeZone></TimeZone>
<MessageDateTime>2020-05-29T07:28:59.421</MessageDateTime>
</ResponseMessageInfo>
<UBUSTransaction>
<Id>null</Id>
<Status>FAILED</Status>
</UBUSTransaction>
<HostTransaction>
<Id>0000</Id>
<Status>FAILURE</Status>
</HostTransaction>
<HostParentTransaction>
<Id>null</Id>
<Status>null</Status>
</HostParentTransaction>
<CustomInfo/>
</ResponseHeader>
</Header>
<Body>
<Error>
<FIBusinessException>
<ErrorDetail><ErrorCode>162</ErrorCode><ErrorDesc>Account does not exist</ErrorDesc><ErrorSource>acct.foracid</ErrorSource><ErrorType>BE</ErrorType></ErrorDetail>
</FIBusinessException>
</Error></Body>
</FIXML>
```

How do I convert it c# objects?.  Because attribute changes.

Answer (score 0):

Create two classes, one for Success and one for Failed message. Depending on `Status Code` parse the response to corresponding class.
If you're thinking to create a dynamical class(es), well you could try using `dynamic` keyword, but `C#` is strong type language.
Also, there is a small tool who can help you create the class from the response, give it a try, here is  the [link.](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

So the glue between your statuses is the header part, so I have separated it in one class.

```cs
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
   public class HeaderDto
   {

       [XmlRoot(ElementName = "RequestMessageKey", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
       public class RequestMessageKey
       {
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "RequestUUID", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string RequestUUID { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "ServiceRequestId", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string ServiceRequestId { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "ServiceRequestVersion", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string ServiceRequestVersion { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "ChannelId", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string ChannelId { get; set; }
       }

       [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ResponseMessageInfo", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
       public class ResponseMessageInfo
       {
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "BankId", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string BankId { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "TimeZone", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string TimeZone { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "MessageDateTime", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string MessageDateTime { get; set; }
       }

       [XmlRoot(ElementName = "UBUSTransaction", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
       public class UBUSTransaction
       {
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string Id { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "Status", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string Status { get; set; }
       }

       [XmlRoot(ElementName = "HostTransaction", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
       public class HostTransaction
       {
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string Id { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "Status", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string Status { get; set; }
       }

       [XmlRoot(ElementName = "HostParentTransaction", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
       public class HostParentTransaction
       {
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string Id { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "Status", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string Status { get; set; }
       }

       [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ResponseHeader", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
       public class ResponseHeader
       {
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "RequestMessageKey", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public RequestMessageKey RequestMessageKey { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "ResponseMessageInfo", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public ResponseMessageInfo ResponseMessageInfo { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "UBUSTransaction", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public UBUSTransaction UBUSTransaction { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "HostTransaction", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public HostTransaction HostTransaction { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "HostParentTransaction", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public HostParentTransaction HostParentTransaction { get; set; }
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "CustomInfo", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public string CustomInfo { get; set; }
       }

       [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Header", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
       public class Header
       {
           [XmlElement(ElementName = "ResponseHeader", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
           public ResponseHeader ResponseHeader { get; set; }
       }
   }
}
```

The Success response class would look something like this...

```cs
/* 
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 */
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static Xml2CSharp.HeaderDto;

namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    public class SuccessDto
    {
        public RequestMessageKey RequestMessageKey { get; set; }
        public ResponseMessageInfo ResponseMessageInfo { get; set; }
        public UBUSTransaction UBUSTransaction { get; set; }
        public HostTransaction HostTransaction { get; set; }
        public HostParentTransaction HostParentTransaction { get; set; }
        public ResponseHeader ResponseHeader { get; set; }
        public Header Header { get; set; }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "AcctType", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class AcctType
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "SchmCode", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string SchmCode { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "SchmType", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string SchmType { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "PostAddr", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class PostAddr
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Addr1", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string Addr1 { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Addr2", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string Addr2 { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Addr3", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string Addr3 { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "City", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string City { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "StateProv", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string StateProv { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "PostalCode", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string PostalCode { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Country", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string Country { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "AddrType", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string AddrType { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BankInfo", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class BankInfo
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "BankId", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string BankId { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "BranchId", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string BranchId { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "BranchName", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string BranchName { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "PostAddr", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public PostAddr PostAddr { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "AcctId", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class AcctId
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "AcctId", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string AcctId { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "AcctType", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public AcctType AcctType { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "AcctCurr", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string AcctCurr { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "BankInfo", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public BankInfo BankInfo { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BalAmt", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class BalAmt
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "amountValue", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string AmountValue { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "currencyCode", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "AcctBal", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class AcctBal
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "BalType", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string BalType { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "BalAmt", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public BalAmt BalAmt { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BalInqRs", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class BalInqRs
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "AcctId", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public AcctId AcctId { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "AcctBal", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public List<AcctBal> AcctBal { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BalInqResponse", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class BalInqResponse
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "BalInqRs", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public BalInqRs BalInqRs { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "BalInq_CustomData", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string BalInq_CustomData { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class Body
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "BalInqResponse", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public BalInqResponse BalInqResponse { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FIXML", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class FIXML
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public Header Header { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public Body Body { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
            public string SchemaLocation { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
            public string Xmlns { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
            public string Xsi { get; set; }
        }
    }

}
```

And Failed class would be like this

```cs
/* 
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 */
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static Xml2CSharp.HeaderDto;

namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    public class FailedDto
    {
        public RequestMessageKey RequestMessageKey { get; set; }
        public ResponseMessageInfo ResponseMessageInfo { get; set; }
        public UBUSTransaction UBUSTransaction { get; set; }
        public HostTransaction HostTransaction { get; set; }
        public HostParentTransaction HostParentTransaction { get; set; }
        public ResponseHeader ResponseHeader { get; set; }
        public Header Header { get; set; }


        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ErrorDetail", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class ErrorDetail
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ErrorCode", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ErrorDesc", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string ErrorDesc { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ErrorSource", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string ErrorSource { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ErrorType", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public string ErrorType { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FIBusinessException", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class FIBusinessException
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ErrorDetail", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public ErrorDetail ErrorDetail { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Error", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class Error
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "FIBusinessException", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public FIBusinessException FIBusinessException { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class Body
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Error", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public Error Error { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "FIXML", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
        public class FIXML
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public Header Header { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://www.finacle.com/fixml")]
            public Body Body { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
            public string SchemaLocation { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
            public string Xmlns { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
            public string Xsi { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Please consider this as pseudo code, since it's not tested.
So when you get the response, parse the header, and read the node you need to validate if its Success or Failed message, then just parse it as that object.

Comment: Can I directly extract Status node without tracing from the root node?.  Because while converting to object it throws an exception if any of the node is not converted to c# class

Comment: After some investigation of your response, failed and successful, i see some similar stuff.
Both of your messages have same Request Header object as I can see. So your header can be the one calss and the Body result can be dynamic (two separate classes, depending on what status it is)
That way you can achive what you wanted with reading Status field.

Comment: can you please help me on this?

Comment: Thank you @arcticwhite